# How do you refresh an XCode asset catalog when the source images are changed

Tags: xcode, catalog, assets

I am generating my App Icons for Xcode and when I rebuild them, the asset catalog doesnt reflect it. This used to work correctly before Asset Catalog's where available, so is there a new way to update it?

Comment: How do you update them? When I edit images in Photoshop and save them, changes are reflected immediately in the asset catalog.

Comment: i overwrite the files in the xcode project.

Comment: As long as names are the same, it should work.